# What is "error A2008: syntax error: integer" and how do I solve it?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

What is "error A2008: syntax error: integer" and how do I solve it?

before, I have the `error A2008: syntax error : .` and `error A2008: syntax error : integer`

, then I looked at one post, asking me to download older version of MASM, which I did, and the `.` error was resolved but `error A2008: syntax error : integer` is still there.

```
;.586
.MODEL flat,C

longestSequence PROTO, theArrayOFFSET:PTR DWORD, theArraySize: DWORD ;proto declaration

;.data

.code




longestSequence PROC USES esi edi eax ebx ,
theArrayOFFSET: PTR DWORD,
theArraySize: DWORD

LOCAL temp: DWORD 10 DUP(?) //error happens here
LOCAL lengthc: DWORD


; some irrelevant code
```

I am sure I declared the LOCAL correctly, seems like something is happening with the size of the `temp` array. (I am trying to call this procedure from a c++ method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locals have a different syntax for arrays.

It's `LOCAL label [ [count] ] [:type] [, label [ [count] ] [type] ] ...`

So your `temp` array would be:

```
LOCAL temp[10]:DWORD
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/local-masm?view=vs-2019) for `LOCAL`.